# A pseudocompact space with $G_\delta$-point

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is evert $T_2$ pseudocompact space with $G_\delta$-points always  first countable? Does there exist a counterexample?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: What is your definition of pseudocompact for non-Tychonoff spaces?

Comment: It is true if we replace pseudocompact by feebly compact (which is equivalent to it for Tychonoff spaces) and Hausdorffness is strengthened to $T_3$.

Answer (score 4):

I recall that a space $X$ is called *pseudocompact* in our mathematical school or
*feebly compact*, for instance, in Mikhail Tkachenko's school provided
each locally finite family of nonempty open subsets of the space $X$ is
finite.

Yesterday I have posed this question at the divertissement at
our seminar “[Topology & Applications](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/index.html)”
and then my friend [Oleg Gutik](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/Gutik_mine.html) and me answered it.

We construct an example as follows. Let $X_0$ be a
non-empty $T_1$ space. Determine a topology on the set
$X=(X_0\times\omega)\cup\{y_0\}$, where $y_0\not\in X_0\times\omega$ by the following base
$\mathcal B=\{U\times \{n\}: U$ is an open subset of the space $X_0, n\in\omega \}\cup
\{\{y_0\}\cup\bigcup_{m\ge n}X_0\setminus F_m: n\in\omega$, $F_m$ is a finite subset of the space $X_0$ for each $m\in\omega$ such that $m\ge n$}.

It is easy to check the following:

- the space $X$ is Hausdorff provided the space $X_0$ is Hausdorff;
- the space $X$ is pseudocompact provided the space $X_0$ is a pseudocompact space without isolated
  points;
- each point of the space $X$ is $G_\delta$ provided each point of the space $X_0$ is $G_\delta$;
- the point $y_0$ has uncountable character provided the space $X_0$ is infinite.

So this construction yields the negative answer to you question if we take the unit segment as $X_0$.

Comment: I corrected some gaps from the first versions of the answer.